# How to get the first two digits of a large float number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I want to get the first two digits of a large float number e.g from `1115487.2644548` i want to get returned `11.154872644548`.
Which Javascript native function to use to achieve such operation.

PS :  `toPrecision(2)` isn't what i want.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could adjust by using the logarithm of ten.

```js
function getTwo(v) {
    return v / 10 ** (Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.floor(v))) - 1);
}

console.log(getTwo(1115487.2644548));
console.log(getTwo(111.54872644548));
console.log(getTwo(11154.872644548));
console.log(getTwo(99999));
console.log(getTwo(999.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875));
```

Comment: You are inspiring as always :)

Comment: Given 999.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875, this produces 9.9999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875 but the answer according to the problem specification, as closely as it can be represented in IEEE-754 binary64 floating-point, is 99.999999999999985789145284797996282577514648437.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, that is the problem with floating point arithmetic. if if a mathematical working solution, it could be wrong.

Comment: The fact that floating-point operations have rounding errors explains why this function returns incorrect results. It does not change the fact that this function does return incorrect results and therefore has a bug.

Comment: @EricPostpischil, what is the bug of the function?

Comment: The bug is that, in some cases, such as the the one I showed, the function returns a result different from the result it is desired to give by the specification in the problem. That is the definition of a bug: A deviation between software and its specification.

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic is designed to approximate real arithmetic. In this case, with input 999.9999999999998863131622783839702606201171875, a good approximation of the desired result would be 99.999999999999985789145284797996282577514648437. Instead, the function returns 9.9999999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875, which is off by a factor of ten. That is not a reasonable amount of error. In this case, the reason for the excessive error is using a discontinuous function in the algorithm, `floor`, without designing around the problems that causes.

Comment: When functions are continuous and have modest derivatives, they map small errors to small errors, and these can be chained together without magnifying the rounding errors greatly. But a function that is discontinuous may map a small error to a huge error. In this case, a small difference between the logarithms—999.999…5 has a common logarithm slightly under 3, while the `log10` function returns 3, is mapped to a large difference by `floor`—the desired result in this case would be 2, but it produces 3. So you cannot write good floating-point code just by slapping functions together.

Comment: In this problem, it is known the desired answer is in the interval [10, 100). So, after making an initial attempt, the function could test whether its answer is in that interval, and, if it is not, adjust it. However, further analysis would be necessary to determine whether this always produces an acceptable answer. E.g., for any input that is exactly a power of 10, OP likely wants 10 as a result, and 99.999…5 would not be acceptable. Similarly, for any input that is slightly under a power of 10, OP likes wants 99.999…5 (or 99) as a result, and 10 would not be acceptable.

Comment: thank you for the explanations. finally i take the integer value which should work for numbers >= 1.

Answer (score 1):

Simple [division](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Division)

```js
const num = 1115487.2644548;

console.log(num/100000);

console.log(parseInt(num/100000));
```

If the length of the integer is unknown, try this - other answers shows log versions

```js
const num = 1115487.2644548;

const len = String(parseInt(num)).length
const two = len-2;
console.log(num/10**two); // without testing the len > 2
```

Comment: In case OP doesn't know the "length" i.e. magnitude of the nu8mber beforehand, he can first get the logarithm.